# use regex to separate a list of serial numbers into multiple lists with matched prefix

Tags: python, regex

The question comes from [How to separate a list of serial numbers into multiple lists with matched prefix?](//stackoverflow.com/q/66436802/how-to-separate-a-list-of-serial-numbers-into-multiple-lists-with-matched-prefix/66437748?noredirect=1#comment117453961_66437748) on Stack Overflow.

Input:

> ```
> sn = ['bike-001', 'bike-002', 'car/001', 'bus/for/001', 'car/002', 'bus/for/002']
> ```

Intended output:

> ```
> # string with same prefix will be in the same list, e.g.:
>
> sn1 = ['bike-001', 'bike-002']
> sn2 = ['car/001', 'car/002']
> sn3 = ['bus/for/001', 'bus/for/002']
> ```

The original thread already had a brilliant answer using `.startswith(<sub_str>)`, however I still want to use `regex` to solve the question.

Here's what I've tried: I use `re.sub()` to get the prefix and `re.search()` to get the 3-digits serial number. I'd like to know if there is a better way (like using one-time `regex` function) to get the solution.

```
import re

sn = ['bike-001', 'bike-002', 'car/001', 'bus/for/001', 'car/002', 'bus/for/002']
sn_dict = {}
for item in sn:
    category = re.sub(r'\d{3}', "", item)
    number = re.search(r'\d{3}', item).group()
    if category not in sn_dict.keys():
        sn_dict[category] = []
    sn_dict[category].append(category + number)
```

After running the script we will have the following `sn_dict`:

```py
{
    'bike-': ['bike-001', 'bike-002'], 
    'car/': ['car/001', 'car/002'], 
    'bus/for/': ['bus/for/001', 'bus/for/002']
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `re.findall`. Instead of iterating over each string, you can combine all the serial numbers into one string and use `regex` to find all the matches (this implementation assumes there are no spaces in the serial number).

```
import re

string_list = ['bike-001', 'bike-002', 'car/001', 'bus/for/001', 'car/002', 'bus/for/002']
string = ' '.join(string_list)
matches = re.findall(r"([^0-9])", string)
numbers = re.findall(r"([0-9]{3})", string)
prefixes = ''.join(c for c in matches).split()
result_dict = {}
for prefix, number in zip(prefixes, numbers):
    if prefix not in result_dict.keys():
        result_dict[prefix] = []
    result_dict[prefix].append(prefix + number)
```

The first `re.findall` searches for any string that is *not* a number. The second finds *any* succession of three numbers. The next line combines the characters in `matches`, and since we denoted that we separated each serial number by `' '`, we can split using the same value. Then, we use the same code present in your question to populate the result dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of what we accept, it might be worth anchoring the digit-string to the end of the `item` with `$`.

The code looks to be reimplementing quite a lot of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  Assuming we don't care about order, we could easily re-write to build off that by sorting the input and passing a suitable `key` function.

Alternatively, write a more general `split_to()` function that accepts a `key` function in a similar manner to `groupby`, so we can separate the general mechanism from the particular instance we have here.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you can avoid concatenating and recombining strings and instead just match against the prefix and add to dict directly from there.

```py
import re

string_list = ['bike-001', 'bike-002', 'car/001', 'bus/for/001', 'car/002', 'bus/for/002']
result_dic = {}
for item in string_list:
  prefix = re.match("([^0-9]+)", item).group()
  if prefix not in result_dic:
    result_dic[prefix] = []
  result_dic[prefix].append(item)
```